# Parsec error when using char in different context

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to support String variables in my language and have found the parser which I need:

```
strP :: Parser String
strP = between (char '"') (char '"') (many1 $ noneOf "\"")
```

and I can use it from GHCi but when I add it to my code in:

```
stri = Val <$> VString <$> (between (char '"') (char '"') (many1 $ noneOf "\""))
```

it complains that

```
No instance for (Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s0 m0 Char)
  arising from a use of `char'
The type variables `s0', `m0' are ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

But honestly I have no idea what the types should be :/

Comment: The type will probably be `Parser X`, where X is the type that `Val` produces. I believe this has to do with the monomorphism restriction, so added `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to your file may fix it.

Comment: Now that I think of it it does sound silly that I didn't try that but I suppose I need a lot more practice with this to grok it. It didn't occur to me that simply stating `:: Parser Char` would provide the info he needed. How come the ghci gets it?

Comment: ghci has `NoMonomorphismRestriction` enabled. from https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction: The monomorphism restriction is turned on by default in compiled modules, and turned off by default at the GHCi prompt (since GHC 7.8.1).